Varchar str_to_date incorrect datetime value part 2
Following up on my previous question here:  Varchar str_to_date incorrect datetime value
I was able to update a VARCHAR CreatedDate column to a date format using the below query:
UPDATE table1 SET CreatedDate = date(str_to_date(CreatedDate, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p')) 

Using the above query, I was able to make the VARCHAR CreatedDate date go from this:
9/9/2023 12:29:12 PM

To this:
2023-09-09

The table structure looks like this:
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `SubscriberID` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedDate` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StatusText` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `EmailAddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `LastClickDate` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastOpenDate` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastSendDate` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastUnsubscribeDate` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `esp` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `property` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isp_group` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

Focusing on just the date columns, I tried to write the same query to update the LastClickDate column, like this:
UPDATE `table1` SET `LastClickDate` = date(str_to_date(`LastClickDate`, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p')) 

I get the below error:
#1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date

I don't understand how the query worked for CreatedDate but not LastClickDate.  I am perplexed.
I tried to remove the backticks `` from the tablename and the column names, but that didn't work either.
There are blank dates in the remaining columns with dates. If it's the blanks that are causing the problem, how I can update my UPDATE query to take account for the blanks? If I can get the blanks to update to 0000-00-00, that would be helpful.

You have some rows with an empty value in that column. SELECT SubscriberID FROM table1 WHERE lastClickDate = '' will find them.

Use IF() or CASE to assign a default value when lastClickDate = ''

SET lastClickDate = IF(lastClickDate = '', 'default value', date(str_to_date(...)))

@Barmar I tried this: UPDATE table1 SET LastClickDate = IF(LastClickDate = '', '0000-00-00', DATE(str_to_date(LastClickDate, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p')) but got an error.

Don't be afraid of NULL values.

@jarlh Are you suggesting that I update the blanks to NULLs?

Well, at least consider it.

If it were me, I would add a new column named something like CreationDate, and then use the update query to set values in the new column rather than the existing column. You can map the blanks to NULL values, as previously suggested. When I was done, I would DROP the old column and rename the new to match. You have no business storing dates in varchar format in the first place. I'd do a similar transition for LastClickDate with a temporary name like LatestClickDate. Sadly, this may also mean updating application code to know how to do INSERTs/UPDATEs.

@JoelCoehoorn - this project is turning into a nightmare.  I will consider your suggestion though.

Using real date columns is one way to have things be somewhat LESS of a nightmare.

@JoelCoehoorn So I was able to take the first column, CreatedDate, and change it from a VARCHAR to a DATE after the query updated.  I just need to get the other dates to update.

@JohnBeasley That's good news. It seems like you are losing information, though, with the time portion truncated away. You may also want to try for a DateTime conversion.

I support using NULL instead of 0000-00-00. That isn't a real date on any calendar I've ever seen.

@BillKarwin I am updating all the blank dates to NULLs now.  I will then attempt to run the original query to fix the dates.

with a where ... is not null

Sheesh - I finally got all of the dates the way I need them to be, with the help of all of you fine folk.  I used NULL to fix the blanks, converted the dates, then updated the database structure for the VARCHAR date columns to actual DATE columns.  Thank you all.

Why would date columns not DATETIME.  You will just make your life hard.

date(str_to_date(CreatedDate, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p')) is obviously excess, str_to_date(CreatedDate, '%m/%d/%Y')) is enough. https://dbfiddle.uk/p-pX1aFD

Option 1: COALESCE
You can use the COALESCE function if there are NULLs in the field.
It works like this: COALESCE(<field/value to use if value is not NULL>, <field or value to use if the first parameter returns NULL>).
In your case, do this:
UPDATE `table1`
SET `LastClickDate` = COALESCE(date(str_to_date(`LastClickDate`, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p'), '1970-01-01') 

1970-01-01 is the Epoch date.
1900-01-01 is fine too, but 0000-01-01 is not a valid date in computing.
If you still run into an issue, that is because the conversion of string to date failed. Some flavours of SQL have SAFE_CAST etc so that it returns NULL if it fails, and the COALESCE then falls back to the second parameter. However, I can't see that MySQL supports safecasting.
In MySQL the conversion of a zero length string will not safely return a NULL and so the COALESCE will fail.
Option 2: CASE to handle the NULLs and blanks
Take care of the NULLs and blanks first.
UPDATE `table1`
SET `LastClickDate` = 
    CASE 
        WHEN `LastClickDate` IS NULL THEN '1970-01-01'
        WHEN TRIM(`LastClickDate`) = "" THEN '1970-01-01'
        ELSE date(str_to_date(`LastClickDate`, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p')
    END


unfortunately, with STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, warnings in str_to_date in an update statement produce an error, even if you wrap it in coalesce.   https://dbfiddle.uk/eVDjFZmx

Your example inserts zero length strings in a date field via the bar field AND COALESCE to ‘’ which will error. I didn’t suggest doing that. My COALESCE replaces NULLs with a date value, not with a zero length string. If the original date field contains a zero length string, then the CASE statement will work but the COALESCE will fail.

That is to say, the incoming value of ‘’ will not trigger COALESCE, but even if it was triggered by NULLs, setting the COALESCE to ‘’ for a date field will cause it to fail.
